# How to Enable Main Items & Button in Application Button in MFC

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I'm developing an **MFC application dedicated to Windows 7 GUI** on visual studio 2013.
 What I've done so far is I've added **Main Item and Button into Application Button** by getting some help from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354414.aspx as you can see in below image
[image: My Application Demo].
Now, I want to know that how can I add **Event Handler** into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm giving answer of my own question.
I've done this by adding few line of code show below.

In **MainFrm.h** I've declare two public method

```
afx_msg void OnMainItemKasim();
afx_msg void OnButtonKasim();
```

In **MainFrm.cpp**. Define empty stub of both method

```
void CMainFrame::OnMainItemKasim()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
}


void CMainFrame::OnButtonKasim()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
}
```

finally, write following lines in **BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP**

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_KASIM, &CMainFrame::OnMainItemKasim)
ON_COMMAND(ID_APP_KASIM, &CMainFrame::OnButtonKasim)
```

where, **ID_FILE_KASIM** is Main Item below Save As & **ID_APP_KASIM** is button next to Exit button

finally it looks like this
[image: Application Look]